# Dark Souls 3 PS4 Controller on PC

Tags: dark-souls-3

Not yet found a definitive answer to this anywhere yet (most places I look is just people having difficulty with InputMapper and Steam...)

Does Dark Souls 3 on the PC have native support for a PS4 controller connected by USB? Or does this game NEED to have a 3rd party piece of software installed? (DS4Controller/InputMapper etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PS4 controller acts like a DirectInput controller by default, which is being phased out due to Xinput being superior.
While Dark Souls 3 might work with DInput (most games that support controllers also "support" DirectInput) controller, the buttons will be counter-intuitively mapped and it won't be an enjoyable experience.

There is no reason why you shouldn't use DS4Windows with a PS4 controller on PC though, as it emulates an xinput controller while also opening a lot of customization options, like key rebinding including the touchpad, as well as lightbar color change at different battery levels, mouse simulation, etc.

Comment: Can confirm. None of my DS4 controllers work on Dark Souls 3 natively, but as soon as I have any XInput wrapper (like DS4Windows), it works fine. 

There's also a bug with Dark Souls games wherein if you have multiple controllers plugged into your PC it sometimes wouldn't accept input from them.

Comment: It's sad that they haven't resolved the multiple controller issue, since every time I want to play Dark Souls, I need to uninstall my Logitech G13 gameboard, which isn't even a controller, it just happens to have a joystick.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that DS4Windows requires the option 'Hide DS4 Controller' in the settings before this would work with my Dark Souls 3. (I also had to run DS4Windows as administrator, but this was due to the User I was running it under)

Comment: Hopefully on-topic, I recommend using Ryochan7's fork of DS4Windows, as it is under active development. That said, I am not aware of what the changes are since Jays2Kings' last release. https://github.com/Ryochan7/DS4Windows

Answer (score -4):

Make sure that you are plugging into a usb and not a usb3

Comment: Why would this make a difference with PS4 controllers?

Comment: USB 3.0 is backward compatible with USB 2.0 and USB 1.1 devices, which covers just about the last 20 years worth of USB devices. I highly doubt a PS4 controller would be incompatible with a particular USB port...

Comment: I can confirm that PS4 controller works perfectly fine plugged in a usb3 port